# The Jetpack Compose project doesn't build after I add an anonymous class to it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to add Jetpack Compose to my project, but after making all changes to my `build.gradle` file I'm not able to build it. And the reason is having anonymous classes in the project.

Instead of describing my project, `build.gradle` file and all changes I made, I used the [android-compose-codelabs](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/BasicsCodelab) project as a sandbox.

So basically, I clone the BasicsCodelab project and can successfully build it, but after adding this block at the end of `onCreate` method (`MainActivity.kt`):

```
val listener = object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
        return false
    }
    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
SearchView(this).setOnQueryTextListener(listener)
```

and clearing the project I'm unable to build it anymore. **So, adding an anonymous class to your project (with Jetpack Compose) leads to build failure.**

Error:

```
LiveLiterals$MainActivityKt.class

    com.android.tools.r8.errors.b: Space characters in SimpleName 
    'Boolean$fun-onQueryTextSubmit$class-$no name provided$$val-listener$fun-onCreate$class-MainActivity' 
    are not allowed prior to DEX version 040
```

I assume the `no name provided` part is the reason (should be `no-name-provided`?) but I'm not that familiar with building pipeline to figure out the problem. I tried to disable R8 but no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is fixed in version `1.0.0-alpha02` of Jetpack Compose.

Answer (score 5):

This was discussed a few times in Kotlinlang Slack this week, notably [this thread](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1598482524280700) and [this thread](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1598602553391400).

This is a known bug tracked internally, though I don't see a public bug report for it in the issue tracker. The workaround is to make a regular named subclass, not an anonymous class:

```kotlin
class MyQueryTextListener : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
        return false
    }
    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}

val listener = MyQueryTextListener()

SearchView(this).setOnQueryTextListener(listener)
```